# size of button in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

[image]

I want to control size of button , I use Method setBounds But there is no change
and this my code

```
       public class levels extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

 //Variables 
private static JLabel chooseLevel;
private static JButton easyPuzzle;
private static JButton mediumPuzzle;
private static JButton hardPuzzle;
 // End Of Variables
```

this main cod

```
public static void main(String[]args){

levels level = new levels();
level.setBounds(400, 190, 450, 450);
level.setVisible(true); // frame is visible
level.setResizable(false); // not Resizable frame 
level.setTitle("Puzzle Number : New Game");  // Title Of the frame
```

Container  to add components

```
   Container cN = level.getContentPane(); //  Container to add components for farme 1
   GridLayout gN = new GridLayout(0,1,10,20); //object from GridLayout
   cN.setLayout(gN);

   levels.chooseLevel = new JLabel("              Choose a level :");
   levels.easyPuzzle = new JButton("Easy puzzle from ( 1 - to -15)");
   levels.mediumPuzzle = new JButton("Medium Puzzle from (1- to- 29)");
   levels.hardPuzzle = new JButton("Hard Puzzle from (1- to- 59)");
```

> > ```
> >     //add components for frame
> > ```

```
     cN.add(chooseLevel);
     cN.add(easyPuzzle);
     cN.add(mediumPuzzle);
     cN.add(hardPuzzle);
   }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

The `LayoutManager` overrides the bounds you set many times, and this is the case with `GridLayout`.

I suggest you go through the [layout managers tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Comment: Yes
I know this solution but my teacher does not want
I do not like form the button and, I want to minimize it

Comment: @Seetah tell to your teacher that not using `LayoutManagers` in real life is a fast-track to getting fired. Those things were invented for a reason

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`setPreferredSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) method on the button, although the layout manager has the final word on what size is used in the end.

Answer (score 1):

to my understandings, GridLayout does not let you resize the components inside the parent component. Use another layout and use

```
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizeX,sizeY));
```

or

```
button.setSize(new Dimension(sizeX,sizeY));
```

where sizeX is width and sizeY is height.